# Sequential nonlinear optimization libraries in C++ WITH constraints

Tags: c++, nonlinear-optimization

Are there any good libraries in c++ for sequential nonlinear optimization with constraints?

I am looking for inequality constraints and/or upper and lower bounds.

There is a [stackoverflow question](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/) already for this but not all of them have constraints.

I know of [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt), but it doesn't work well for my specific problem. Are there any others?

---

I finally found the solution that i was looking for if any one else is interested [lpOpt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One SQP algorithm that you could try is [DONLP2](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/fbereiche/numerik/staff/spellucci/DONLP2/). It was originally written in Fortran 77 but there is an ANSI C version as well. It uses dense algebra, so it is primarily suitable for small to medium-sized problems. It is free for academic use. You need to request the code directly from the author, follow the instructions in the link.

**UPDATE** [Sequential Quadratic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) is only one approach to solving non-linear objective functions with constraints, there is also for example [interior point methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method). One very good large-scale open-source C++ alternative that applies the interior point approach is [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt/) (already mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11458668/650012)). There is also for example the commercial package [KNITRO](http://www.ziena.com/knitro.htm). If you cannot or do not want to provide objective function and constraints gradients, you could also have a look at COBYLA2, of which a C version can be downloaded [here](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/other_software/COBYLA_C.tar.gz).

For further inspiration, you could also consult the [Decision Tree For Optimization Software](http://plato.asu.edu/guide.html), which lists different optimization codes suitable for a wide range of different problems.

Comment: @pyCthon I noticed that you found Ipopt by yourself. I have edited my answer based on your finding, and also included some additional links. Albeit a little late, I hope you will still find them useful.